# Finding A Transition Matrix from two bases

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, complex-numbers, matrix-equations

If I have two ordered $\Bbb C$-bases $${B={t^2+t+1, t+1, 1}}$$ $$B'={i,it,it^2}$$ with those B's being part of the complex vector space $P$ of polynomials in $t$ of degree at most 2 having complex coefficients.How in the world do I find a matrix M that translates between coordinates with respect to my two bases.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Note that:
$$
\begin{cases}
t^2+t+1=-i(it^2)-i(it)-i(i)\\
t-1=0(it^2)-i(it)-i(i)\\
1=0(it^2)+0(it)-i(i)
\end{cases}
$$

can you see the matrix?

Comment: Awesome... here is what I had so far but was unsure about. $B' = {i, it, it^2}$ is a basis of $P^3$. So along any vector v in $P^3$ can be written in terms of $B'$ aka (with your help plugged in)$$c_{B'}(b_1)=c_{B'}(t^2+t+1) = -i(it^2)-i(it)-i(i)$$ $$c_{B'}(b_2)=c_{B'}(t+1) = 0(it^2)-i(it)-i(i)$$ $$c_{B'}(b_3)=c_{B'}(1) = 0(it^2)-0(it)-i(i)$$ is this correct so far @Emilio

Comment: which would then give me $
         \begin{pmatrix}
         v_1 \\
         v_2 \\
         v_3  \\
         \end{pmatrix}
 $ = $
         \begin{pmatrix}
         -i & 0 & 0 \\
         -i & -i & 0 \\
         -i & -i & -i &  \\
         \end{pmatrix}
 $ $
         \begin{pmatrix}
         it^2\\
         it \\
         i  \\
         \end{pmatrix}
 $ making my M transition matrix  $$
         \begin{pmatrix}
         -i & 0 & 0 \\
         -i & -i & 0 \\
         -i & -i & -i &  \\
         \end{pmatrix}
 $$ is this kind of the correct path @EmilioNovati

Comment: Yes, correct. Now this matrix ant its inverse are the transformation matrices from the two basis.